# Run through a range of cells and change the date of a linked cell more efficiently

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which will populate a range of around 216 cells, and 25/30 sheets with an index + match lookup to a separate spreadsheet for each column. (See below table.)
The more months that proceed, the larger this will get.

Each month the string that will be looked up will vary, and I need to show the evolution of elements pertaining to this string for each month since an inception date.

I tried two ways, both of which are fairly slow (typically ~30 secs to populate a sheet).

The first method populates the required range with the lookup formula, and then loops through using the replace function to update the formula to include the columns date.

E.g. pseudo-code.

```
For j = 1 To 10
    
    s_Date = Format(ws.cells(1,1).value,"yyyy.mm.dd") 'eg say 5/31/2019
    s_DStep = Format(ws.cells(1,j).value,"yyyy.mm.dd")'eg say 6/30/2019
        
    For k = 10 To 17
        s_formula = ws.Cells(k, j).Formula
        s_formula = Replace(s_formula, s_Date, s_DStep)
        ws.Cells(k, j).Formula = s_formula
    Next k
        
Next j
```

The second method loops through the range, it will assign the cell with the required formula and date.

Simplified example:

```
For j = 1 To i_NumOfDates + 1
    s_DStep = Format(ws.cells(1,j).value,"yyyy.mm.dd")'eg say 6/30/201   
    ws.Cells(10, j + 1) = "=INDEX('" & s_Dir & s_DStep & "\[ Workbook]Sheet1'!$E$1:$E$9999,MATCH($B$2,'" _
      & s_Dir & s_DStep & "\["Workbook]Sheet1'!$a$1:$a$9999,0))"
next j
```

Neither of these methods are quick enough.

I appreciate that lookup formulas are taxing in terms of computing power.

I have done the below.

```
'Turn off Screen Update
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Turn off Automatic Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlManual
    
'Turn off display alert
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

| 5/31/2019 | 6/30/2019 |
| --- | --- |
| =Index(dir & 5.31.2019 & range1, match(str,dir & 5.31.2019 & range2),0) | =Index(dir & 6.30.2019 & range1, match(str,dir & 6.30.2019 & range2),0) |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try copying the formulas to an array, processing it and copying it back to the sheet

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo()

   Dim ar1, ar, j As Long, k As Long
   Dim s_Date As String, s_DStep As String
   Dim rng As Range, ws As Worksheet

   Set ws = Sheet1
   Set rng = ws.Range("A10:J17")
   ar = rng.Formula
   ar1 = ws.Range("A1:J1").Value

   s_Date = Format(ar1(1, 1), "yyyy.mm.dd") 'eg say 5/31/2019
   For j = 1 To UBound(ar, 2) '
        s_DStep = Format(ar1(1, j), "yyyy.mm.dd") 'eg say 6/30/2019
        
        For k = 1 To UBound(ar)
           ar(k, j) = Replace(ar(k, j), s_Date, s_DStep)
        Next k
    Next j
    rng.Formula = ar
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks, this works a charm. I'm familiar with arrays and their benefits so not sure why I never thought to use them for a task like this. Thanks again for your help!